# Windows Driver/Rootkit Development - function pointer - STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c, function-pointers, wdk, rootkit

This is quite a difficult problem to explain online, but I can't figure out what's going on and I really need help, so here goes!

Basically, I have written a security software (as a kernel driver) that will eventually hook every method in the SSDT (System Service Descriptor Table) for Windows XP - 32 bit. Everytime a system call is made, I log it in a file.

My issue arose when I hooked ZwOpenFile because that is a system call that MY code also makes to open the log file to write to it. So I got a Kernel stack overflow error because something would call ZwOpenFile, then I would try log it, my logger (which is part of my driver) would then call ZwOpenFile which would then call ZwOpenFile and so on and so forth until I had filled up the Stack enough to cause a blue screen of death.

In order to get around this, I decided, that everytime the logger function is called, it will also be supplied with a pointer to the old, unhooked, ZwOpenFile function so it could call that directly rather than go through my hooked function and create a recursive mess. However, when the logger calls the ZwOpenFile function pointer that it is supplied with as a parameter, it gets a STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER error. If the ZwOpenFile is called directly (as opposed to through the pointer) it works perfectly! But when the pointer to what should be the same function with the SAME parameters is called, it throws the STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER error code! However, the pointer must be pointing to the correct function as otherwise it wouldn't throw this Windows error message. Here's small and (hopefully) digestible snippets of my code to make more sense:

```
*mydriver.h*
    #define UNICODE
    #define _UNICODE
    #include <ntddk.h>
    #include <ntstrsafe.h>

    #define OPEN_FILE_INDEX 0x74

    NTSTATUS newZwOpenFile(
        PHANDLE FileHandle, 
        ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess, 
        POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes, 
        PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, 
        ULONG ShareAccess, 
        ULONG OpenOptions);

    typedef NTSTATUS (*ZwOpenFilePtr)(
        PHANDLE FileHandle, 
        ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess, 
        POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes, 
        PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, 
        ULONG ShareAccess, 
        ULONG OpenOptions);

*mydriver.c*
    #include "mydriver.h"
    #include "filehandling.c"        

    //global definition of pointer at top of mydriver.c file    
    ZwOpenFilePtr oldZwOpenFile;

    NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT  pDriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING pRegistryPath){
       ...
       ...
       //hooks the SSDT using the index of ZwOpenFile in the SSDT
       oldZwOpenFile = (ZwOpenFilePtr)hookSSDTWithIndex(OPEN_FILE_INDEX, (BYTE*)newZwOpenFile, (DWORD*)systemCallTable);
       ...
       ...
    }

    //inside the method body of every hooked function, there is, at some point, the a call to the logger. 
    //This is shown in the context of newZwOpenFile
    NTSTATUS newZwOpenFile(PHANDLE FileHandle, ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess, POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes, PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, ULONG ShareAccess, ULONG OpenOptions){
      ...         
      driverWriteFile(&uFullString, &uProcess, *oldZwOpenFile);
      ...
    }

*filehandling.c*
    #include <ntstrsafe.h>

    //the logger file
    //the function doing the opening and writing
    NTSTATUS driverWriteFile(PUNICODE_STRING stringToLog, PUNICODE_STRING filename, NTSTATUS (*fileOpenFunction)(PHANDLE,ACCESS_MASK,POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES,PIO_STATUS_BLOCK,ULONG,ULONG)) {
      ...
      //the failing call that returns c000000d
      ntstatus = fileOpenFunction(&handle, FILE_APPEND_DATA, &objAttr, &ioStatusBlock, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT);
      ...
  }
```

What's more is, that, all the hooked functions are spewing out the c000000d error (using DbgPrint), but once or twice, it does somehow succeed... Any help or suggestions would be HUGELY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

at first you call not `ZwOpenFile` but `NtOpenFile`. at second when you call `ZwOpenFile` from kernel *PreviousMode* is kernel mode and `IopCreateFile` not check parameters (kernel trust for kernel). when you call `NtOpenFile` *PreviousMode* can be user mode and parameters is checked. and you use invalid parameters in call `NtOpenFile` - you use `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT` option but not ask for `SYNCHRONIZE` in desired access. so you and must got `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

Comment: firsty, thank you so, so much!! You've saved me a lot of time!! You're right! I've actually hooked NtOpenFile and so parameters aren't checked! I've fixed the synchronize problem, so now I'm calling: `ZwOpenFile(&handle, SYNCHRONIZE, &objAttr, &ioStatusBlock, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT);` 

Now I'm getting a different error (which is good as it means I'm moving forward), I'm getting STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION. Do you have any idea why this might be happening? 

I added null terminators to my Unicode strings by adding a '\0' to the end.

Comment: @Prince - of course you must get `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` because you call **not** `ZwOpenFile` **but** `NtOpenFile` and [**PreviousMode**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559860(v=vs.85).aspx) - is **UserMode**. from another side say `&ioStatusBlock` in your stack - so kernel address. as result when parameters checked - `If the buffer was allocated in system memory instead of in user-mode memory, the ProbeForXxx routine raises an exception, and the NtXxx routine returns the STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION error code.` - this is very basic things..

Comment: @Prince are you understand PreviousMode ? look like you full novice in kernel. way call Zw* functions when you use kernel mode addresses and somehow determinate recursive  calls (that you already call Zw*) or allocate user mode buffers. and finally hook SSDT is wrong and not actual more than 10 years already